# Searching public domain works from a particular scholar

Tags: public-domain

This is a general question, but I have a specific example in mind.

I'm interested to search Francis Galton's works to see if he ever mentioned Condorcet. Galton died in 1911 so all his works would now be in public domain.

So far the best solution I could find was a google search targeted towards a website that contains a lot of his works.

https://www.google.com/search?q=condorcet+site:http://galton.org

Is there a better way?

Comment: Google books might be worth a try, although they might be missing some of his works or there might be OCR errors, but there is at least [one hit](https://www.google.de/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=inauthor%3A%22Francis+Galton%22+condorcet)

Comment: Just because the writings are not under copyright (in the public domain) anymore does not imply that they are easily accessible (by computer or otherwise).

Comment: Visit a good library?

Comment: @Daniel: Visit a good library, and do what when you arrive?

Comment: @GEdgar: Ask the librarian for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try Google Scholar, e.g.,

https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?as_yhi=1911&q=Condorcet+author%3AFrancis+Galton